# Flow variable is not working for Passphrase attribute in SFTP Outbound endpoint in Mule

Tags: mule, sftp, mule-component, mulesoft, passphrase

I need to send passphrase through flow variable to passphrase attribute in the SFTP Outbound endpoint. But when value is sent through flow variable it is not working. If i send the value through property file it is working fine. My requirement is to dynamically pass the value through flow variable.

Comment: What's not working? If you throw loggers everywhere, where is it getting missed? Code would be nice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mule 3 SFTP connector doesn't allow a dynamic passphrase nor identity file. Mule 4 does allow it.

An alternative for Mule 3 could be to modify the transport to implement it.